# List hidden sub-directories and sizes

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to get a list of sub-directories with their sizes using PowerShell.

The following PowerShell code does what I want, but it does not work with hidden directories.

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name + ": " + "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB) + " MB" }
```

I tried showing hidden directories in Windows, but that does't work. For now, I just make sure every sub-directory is not hidden, but this is not ideal. Is there like a simple parameter that can force this code to get information for hidden files and folders?

Preferably, I'd like this to work with PowerShell 2.

Comment: -Force did the job.  I was blind.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `-Force` argument for [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) will cause it to include hidden files and directories.

```
Get-ChildItem -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name + ": " + "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB) + " MB" }
```

Comment: Using -Force, I get some folders with "Access Denied".  Can Powershell bypass this to get the size or I actually need to grant permissions?

Comment: Try running PowerShell as Administrator and see if that clears up your Access Denied issues. If you are still getting them then there's not really any options other than modifying permissions, but do that with great care at that point.

Comment: You can also use `Get-ChildItem -Attributes Hidden, !Hidden` or abbreviated to `Get-ChildItem -At H,!H`

Comment: Even the abbreviated `-At H,!H` is longer than `-Force`, so I don't really see the point of using that.