# Searching for files and folders including hidden

Tags: powershell

I currently have this to search though C:\Users looking for a file or folder with a name pattern (WebNavigatorBrowser PUP).  This works well except it will not search and delete in their AppData folder, I assume because it's hidden.  I have not been able to adjust it to look in hidden folders.  Thanks for any help!

```
get-childitem -path 'C:\Users' -Recurse  -Filter "*WebNavigator*" | remove-item  -Force
```

Edit: Looks like adding -Force will search hidden folders

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List hidden sub-directories and sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688848/list-hidden-sub-directories-and-sizes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [-Force](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1), Luke

> -Force
>
> Allows the cmdlet to get items that otherwise can't be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users' -Recurse -Filter "*WebNavigator*" -Force
```

Comment: Odd it's still not finding all the files that are under C:\Users, any thoughts Obi-Won?

Edit: Strike that had errorhandling on.  It's getting permission issues even though it should be running as an admin

Comment: @EvanSullivan Admin cannot automatically see all files. But can give permissions to himself.

Answer (score 0):

**>** ls (or dir) -ah
...and to see the files listed in a single vertical column instead of wide ...
**>** ls -ahw